# OpenCV build from source Windows make error "RC Object"

Tags: python, windows, opencv, makefile, cmake

I downloaded the latest source from github and configured opencv and the contrib modules. I can seem to build. I already turned off FFMPEG, which I manually downloaded the .dll previously, i know that has been a recent problem. I have succeeded in the past. But now i'm getting to

```
[ 50%] Building RC object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj
C:\mingw\bin\windres.exe: invalid option -- W
Usage: C:\mingw\bin\windres.exe [option(s)] [input-file] [output-file]
 The options are:
  -i --input=<file>            Name input file
  -o --output=<file>           Name output file
  -J --input-format=<format>   Specify input format
  -O --output-format=<format>  Specify output format
  -F --target=<target>         Specify COFF target
     --preprocessor=<program>  Program to use to preprocess rc file
     --preprocessor-arg=<arg>  Additional preprocessor argument
  -I --include-dir=<dir>       Include directory when preprocessing rc file
  -D --define <sym>[=<val>]    Define SYM when preprocessing rc file
  -U --undefine <sym>          Undefine SYM when preprocessing rc file
  -v --verbose                 Verbose - tells you what it's doing
  -c --codepage=<codepage>     Specify default codepage
  -l --language=<val>          Set language when reading rc file
     --use-temp-file           Use a temporary file instead of popen to read
                               the preprocessor output
     --no-use-temp-file        Use popen (default)
  -r                           Ignored for compatibility with rc
  @<file>                      Read options from <file>
  -h --help                    Print this help message
  -V --version                 Print version information
FORMAT is one of rc, res, or coff, and is deduced from the file name
extension if not specified.  A single file name is an input file.
No input-file is stdin, default rc.  No output-file is stdout, default rc.
C:\mingw\bin\windres.exe: supported targets: pe-i386 pei-i386 elf32-i386 elf32-little elf32-big srec symbolsrec verilog tekhex binary ihex
make[2]: *** [modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:1517: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/vs_version.rc.obj] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2363: modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:160: all] Error 2
```

cmake gui options

```
Detected version of GNU GCC: 47 (407)
Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.11", but required is at least "3.4" (found C:/Python27/python.exe)
Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.11", but required is at least "3.2" (found C:/Python27/python.exe)
Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
LAPACK requires BLAS
A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
Caffe:   NO
Protobuf:   NO
Glog:   NO
Looking for tiny_dnn.h
Looking for tiny_dnn.h - found
Found tiny-dnn in: C:/Users/Ben/Documents/opencv/build/3rdparty/tinydnn/tiny-dnn-1.0.0a3
The protocol buffer compiler is not found (PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE='PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND')
freetype2:   NO
harfbuzz:    NO
No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
Torch importer has been enabled. To run the tests you have to install Torch ('th' executable should be available) and generate testdata using opencv_extra/testdata/dnn/generate_torch_models.py script.
Tesseract:   NO

General configuration for OpenCV 3.3.0-rc =====================================
  Version control:               f670a99

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            C:/Users/Ben/Documents/opencv_contrib/modules
    Version control (extra):     3.3.0-rc

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2017-07-04T19:39:34Z
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.14393 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.5.0-rc3
    CMake generator:             MinGW Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            C:/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2
      requested:                 SSE2
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 FP16 AVX AVX2
      requested:                 SSE4_1 AVX FP16 AVX2
      SSE4_1 (0 files):          + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (1 files):             + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (2 files):            + SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++ Compiler:                C:/mingw/bin/g++.exe  (ver 4.7.2)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  C:/mingw/bin/gcc.exe
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -O2 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -mstackrealign -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -march=i686 -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections  -msse -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      
    Linker flags (Debug):        
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 vfw32 winmm
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml objdetect phase_unwrapping photo plot reg surface_matching video xphoto bgsegm dnn face fuzzy img_hash imgcodecs shape videoio xobjdetect highgui superres ts bioinspired dpm features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow python2
    Disabled:                    stitching world contrib_world structured_light
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 viz cnn_3dobj cvv dnn_modern freetype hdf matlab sfm

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        build (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.24)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.2)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO
    GDCM:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      avcodec:                   NO
      avformat:                  NO
      avutil:                    NO
      swscale:                   NO
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Parallel framework:            none

  Trace:                         YES ()

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use Intel IPP:               NO
    Use Intel IPP IW:            NO
    Use Intel IPP Async:         NO
    Use Lapack:                  NO
    Use Eigen:                   NO
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  NO
    Use OpenVX:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.11)
    Libraries:                   C:/Python27/libs/libpython27.a (ver 2.7.11)
    numpy:                       C:/Python27/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
    packages path:               C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 NO

  Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Documentation:
    Doxygen:                     NO

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       YES
    Performance tests:           YES
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  C:/Users/Ben/Documents/opencv/build/install

  cvconfig.h is in:              C:/Users/Ben/Documents/opencv/build
-----------------------------------------------------------------

Configuring done
Generating done
```

Is there a cmake flag that gets around this? opencv_core sounds pretty crucial...

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? Happy to improve the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this might be it:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9100

The work around is at the bottom

> Workaround is to turn off CMake option: ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF

Comment: Yes, you need to disable this option from CMake gui